# How to test lambda-calculus?

Tags: c++, function, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, purely-functional

I implemented the lambda-calculus in C++, but now I don't know how to get out of it. I would like to test if my functions return the right thing, but I cant compare the result, since it is a funtion. Does anyone have an idea how I could test my code?

```
    #include <functional>
    
    class function :
            public std::function<function (function)> {
        public: using type =
                std::function<function (function)>;
        public: using type::function;
    };
    
    
    function True = [](function x) {
        return [&](function y) {
            return x;
        };
    };
    
    function False = [](function x) {
        return [&](function y) {
            return y;
        };
    };
    
    
    function If = [](function x) {
        return [&](function y) {
            return [&](function z) {
                return x(y)(z);
            };
        };
    };
    
    
    function And = [](function x) {
        return [&](function y) {
            return x(y)(x);
        };
    };
    
    function Or = [](function x) {
        return [&](function y) {
            return x(x)(y);
        };
    };
    
    // ...
    
    
    int main()
    {
        // ?
    }
```

Comment: Add a tag to `function`?  Use the "get pointer to stored" api?  Pass a null/not null function and use operator bool?

Comment: Thanks @Yakk-AdamNevraumont! I don't want to modify the class `function`, but I can check if i get an exception when I try to call a null-function that gets returned. I will write an answer to my question, when I wrote the tests.

Comment: you could execute the function and assert the result

Comment: `std::function` is not meant to be inherited from, it doesn't have a [virtual destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/~function)

Comment: Thenk you @LorahAttkins! I didn't think about that. I will try to make it a member. Or would you solve that a different way?

Comment: @LorahAttkins I solved the problem by using private inheritance and explicitly made `operator()` and `operator bool` public in the subclass.

Comment: @lora you can inherit from classes without virtual methods.  You just cannot rely on LSP.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Never said you can't, I said you're not meant to, and in the case of `std::function` boy SBS goes out the window. People inheriting from classes that weren't designed as bases are gonna feel it when/if those are marked as `final` in future revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the following test code.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <exception>

template <typename E, typename F>
bool throws(F f)
try {
    f();
    return false;
}
catch (E const &) {
    return true;
}


auto main() -> int
{
    function Null;
    assert(throws<std::bad_function_call>([&] { True(Null)(True)(True); }));
    assert(throws<std::bad_function_call>([&] { False(True)(Null)(True); }));
}
```

The test for `False` worked, but the test for `True` didn't. The first assert did not pass and I don't know why. When I capture `x` by value instead of by reference (`[&]` -> `[=]`) everything works.

New code for `True`:

```
function True = [](function x) {
    return [=](function y) {
        return x;
    };
};
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work if I capture by reference?

Comment: I know this solution is to complicated. I'm rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

My code looks now like this (I just replaced all `[&]` by `[=]` and used private inheritance):

```
class function :
        private std::function<function (function)> {
    public: using type =
            std::function<function (function)>;
    public: using type::function;
    public: using type::operator();
    public: using type::operator bool;
};


function True = [](function t) {
    return [=](function f) {
        return t;
    };
};

function False = [](function t) {
    return [=](function f) {
        return f;
    };
};


function If = [](function x) {
    return [=](function t) {
        return [=](function f) {
            return x(t)(f);
        };
    };
};


function And = [](function x) {
    return [=](function y) {
        return x(y)(x);
    };
};

function Or = [](function x) {
    return [=](function y) {
        return x(x)(y);
    };
};
```

And the tests look like this:

```
auto main() -> int
{
    function Null;

    assert( True(True)(Null));
    assert(!True(Null)(True));

    assert( False(Null)(True));
    assert(!False(True)(Null));

    assert( If(True )(True)(Null));
    assert(!If(True )(Null)(True));
    assert( If(False)(Null)(True));
    assert(!If(False)(True)(Null));

    assert(And(False)(False) (Null)(True));
    assert(And(False)(True ) (Null)(True));
    assert(And(True )(False) (Null)(True));
    assert(And(True )(True ) (True)(Null));

    assert(Or(False)(False) (Null)(True));
    assert(Or(False)(True ) (True)(Null));
    assert(Or(True )(False) (True)(Null));
    assert(Or(True )(True ) (True)(Null));
}
```